# Is there a simpler way to format this timespan?

Tags: .net, time

I'm looking to achieve a time format that looks like this: **2d 4h** remaining; or **1h 36m** remaining; or **35s** remaining, etc. So that it only displays the two largest values of time (this is how Clash of Clans and some other mobile games format wait times.)

Currently my code is below, but I'm wondering if there might be a shorter way to format the timespan in this manner? I'm not fully sure if `String.Format` will work…

```
static function FormatRushTime ( span : System.TimeSpan )
{
    if ( span.Days > 0 )
    {
        var t1 = span.ToString("%d") + "d";
        var t2 = span.Hours > 0 ? ToString("%h") + "h" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Hours > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%h") + "h";
        t2 = span.Minutes > 0 ? ToString("%m") + "m" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Minutes > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%m") + "m";
        t2 = span.Seconds > 0 ? ToString("%s") + "s" : String.Empty;
    }
    else if ( span.Seconds > 0 )
    {
        t1 = span.ToString("%s") + "s";
        t2 = String.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        t1 = String.Empty;
        t2 = String.Empty;
    }

    return t1+" "+t2;
}
```

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, there is a simpler way. Do not reinvent the wheel. This has already been done, no need to write your own function to do it. There is a NuGet package called [Humanizer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekHumanizerMakesNETDataTypesMoreHuman.aspx) that takes care of this. Using this library is as easy as `span.Humanize(2)`;

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Does it only belong on codereview because I included the code? The question would really be asking the same thing without the code example. Where should I have posted had I not included the code?

Comment: It belongs on codereview because you have a working piece of code, and you are just looking for advice on how to improve/optimize it.

Comment: Is there a way to move it or is a matter of delete -> re-post?

Comment: I think that some admin can move it, but would be faster for you to just delete/repost.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin FYI, my question was not accepted at CodeReview as I wasn't asking for my code to be reviewed but for a better approach. Thanks for giving me an unnecessary runaround.

Comment: That sucks, but I can't exactly control what happens on CodeReview can I?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - I am currently chatting with the guys there. For future reference they say that codereview is about the code. Programming questions (like mine) are more suited for here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an external library like [Humanizer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeekHumanizerMakesNETDataTypesMoreHuman.aspx).  Or if you want a down-and-dirty solution you could always just concatenate the components...

```
     TimeSpan rawr = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 1, 1);
     string rawrString = "";

     rawrString += rawr.Days > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%d}d ", rawr) : "";
     rawrString += rawr.Hours > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%h}h ", rawr) : "";
     rawrString += rawr.Minutes > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%m}m ", rawr) : "";
     rawrString += rawr.Seconds > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%s}s ", rawr) : "";
```

In order to only get two time components, you could add a counter:

```
     TimeSpan rawr = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1, 1);
     string rawrString = "";
     int TimeComponentCounter = 0;

     rawrString += rawr.Days > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%d}d ", rawr) : "";
     if (rawrString.Contains("d")) TimeComponentCounter++;
     if (TimeComponentCounter < 2) rawrString += rawr.Hours > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%h}h ", rawr) : "";
     if (rawrString.Contains("h")) TimeComponentCounter++;
     if (TimeComponentCounter < 2) rawrString += rawr.Minutes > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%m}m ", rawr) : "";
     if (rawrString.Contains("m")) TimeComponentCounter++;
     if (TimeComponentCounter < 2) rawrString += rawr.Seconds > 0 ? String.Format("{0:%s}s ", rawr) : "";
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a solution that is separate from an external library. I need it formatted like **1d 4h**, and am I right in thinking your posted solution would display **1d 3h 47m 17s** instead?

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple method via @rolfl on codereview.stackexchange.com:

```
static string FormatRushTime (TimeSpan span )
{
    if ( span.Days > 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}d {1:d}h", span.Days, span.Hours);
    }
    if ( span.Hours > 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}h {1:d}m", span.Hours, span.Minutes);
    }
    if ( span.Minutes > 0 )
    {
        return String.Format("{0:d}m {1:d}s", span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
    }
    return String.Format("{0:d}s", span.Seconds);
}
```